# Keep footer with variable height on bottom

Tags: css, footer

I need to keep a footer on bottom, but its height is variable so main solutions are not suitable for me...

Examples of what I **can't** do:

- http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/
- http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/bottom-footer-demo.htm

Anyone have a solution for flexible footers?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**2014 UPDATE**: The modern way to solve this layout problem is to [use the `flexbox` CSS model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26558049/1269037). It's supported by all major browsers and IE11+.

---

Here's a solution for sticky footer of flexible height using `div`s with `display: table-row`:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
.content {
  display: table-row;
  /* height is dynamic, and will expand... */
  height: 100%;
  /* ...as content is added (won't scroll) */
  background: turquoise;
}
.footer {
  display: table-row;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h3>Sticky footer</h3>
    <p>Footer of variable height</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What needs to be noted is that CSS was designed to layout *documents*, not web application screens. The CSS display: table properties are very valid though, and are supported in [all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-table). This is not the same as using *structural* tables for layout.

Comment: +1, this is really cool. Do you know of any drawbacks to this approach? How do you think it will hold up on mobile?

Comment: This is brilliant -- thank you! It didn't quite fit my needs, however, which was for a variable-height sticky footer and a content area that *would* scroll. I discovered I could do that by omitting "display:table-row" on the content, and setting "overflow-y:scroll". On the footer, I then changed it to "display:table-footer-group". This has caused things to work exactly as desired!

Comment: You should add `table-layout: fixed;` to class wrapper. Without that I had some width issues in IE. The content was overflowing regardless of the maximum width.

Comment: Just to note: Samsung phone browsers use a very old version of chrome and using flexbox to push down the footer results in it floating across the middle of the screen (early 2017)

Comment: `table-layout: fixed;` also fixed an issue with Firefox 53.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if page is higher than browser width? It just doesn't display anything that overflows the screen: main content or footer.

Answer (score -1):

I think I understand what you what.

You need to remove the height css and replace it with padding-top and padding bottom if you still what spacing..

For e.g.

```
#footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background: #6CF;
   padding-top: 20px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
#wrapper, #content, #footer {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: relative;
}


<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ...doesn't create a variable height footer, but scales it to 100% of viewport area.