# How can a variable-height sticky footer be defined in pure CSS?

Tags: css

The key to note here is the height of the footer is not going to be fixed, but will vary with its content.

When I say “sticky footer,” I use it in what I understand to be the common definition of “a footer that is never higher than the bottom of the viewport, but if there is enough content, it will be hidden until the user scrolls down far enough to see it.”

Note also I don’t need to support legacy browsers. If CSS `display: table` & related properties help here, they are fair game.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

All other solutions here are out of date and either use JavaScript, or `table` hacks.

With the advent of the [CSS flex model](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/), solving the variable-height sticky footer problem becomes very, very easy: while mostly known for laying out content in the horizontal direction, Flexbox actually works just as well for vertical layout problems. All you have to do is wrap the vertical sections in a flex container and choose which ones you want to expand. They'll automatically take up all the available space in their container.

Note how simple the markup and the CSS are. No table hacks or anything.

The flex model is [supported by 96%+ of the browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) in use today.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;  /* to avoid scrollbars */
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;  /* use the flex model */
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;  /* learn more: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/ */
}

#header {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;  /* can be variable as well */
}

#body {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#footer{
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">Title</div>
  <div id="body">Body</div>
  <div id="footer">
    Footer<br/>
    of<br/>
    variable<br/>
    height<br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem in IE10 & IE11 is related to [min-height-and-flexbox-flex-direction-column-dont-work-together-in-ie-10-11-preview](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802625/min-height-and-flexbox-flex-direction-column-dont-work-together-in-ie-10-11-preview).

Comment: I also see a problem with the `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%` in the #wrapper, in Chrome on Linux.  It scrolls the whole page with `min-height` and only the body with `height`.

Comment: Best solution after hours of searching

Comment: Great solution! I've first been wondering why you assigned flex=1 to the body – until I saw that it refers to the div (id#body) with the same name. It might be clearer if you renamed it to #main or #content. By the way, is the wrapper div necessary, or could the display:flex simply be assigned to the "real" body?

Comment: If you don't want to set 100% all the way down from html, use `min-height: 100vh`

Comment: For the header and footer to always be on-screen, use this answer, plus the wrapper height set to 100vh, header and footer positions set to sticky, and body flex-direction set to column.

Answer (score 18):

You can absolutely do this in pure CSS.  [Clicky the linky.](http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2011/09/sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way/)

This concept uses `display: table-cell` organize your page sections rather than the normal `display: block`.

**HTML**

```
<body class="Frame">
    <header class="Row"><h1>Catchy header</h1></header>
    <section class="Row Expand"><h2>Awesome content</h2></section>
    <footer class="Row"><h3>Sticky footer</h3></footer>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.Frame {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.Row {
    display: table-row;
    height: 1px;
}
.Row.Expand {
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: While the example code is missing something, yes, it’s possible with this technique.

Comment: You're right!  I've made my edits to correct this, glad it worked for you!

Comment: There's no `table-cell` in the example. Did you mean `table-row`? Anyway, the modern way to do this is to use the [CSS flexbox model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26558049/1269037).

Comment: You should add `table-layout: fixed;` to class Frame. Without that I had some width issues in IE. The content was overflowing regardless of the maximum width.

Comment: @cereallarceny This solved the problem. Thank you. My man ✌

Answer (score -1):

You can stick the footer to the bottom of the viewport just with:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

However that will make it appear even if there's content.

To prevent this, you will need some JavaScript:

```
(window.onscroll = function() {
    var foot = document.getElementById('footer');
    foot.style.position = "static";
    if( foot.offsetTop < document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.offsetHeight - foot.offsetHeight)
        foot.style.position = "fixed";
})();
```

(The `(...)();` wrapper makes the onscroll function get called once when the page loads, since that's needed too)
(The above function is untested, but should work - if it doesn't, let me know and I'll make an actual test page)

Comment: (...)(); is just a self executing fn is it not?

Comment: Yes - this basically makes the function be called once without needing a scroll, and then again every time an onscroll event is fired.

Comment: So this isn't correct? "(The (...)(); wrapper makes the onscroll function get called once when the page loads, since that's needed too)"

Comment: I'm repeating myself, but badly XD Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I follow you now. I did get a little confused but that's a pretty neat way of doing that.