# Footer not sticking to bottom of page when scrolling

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I'm coding a webpage that should have a header on top, a footer on bottom, and a side column on the right side.  I'm having trouble with getting the footer to be on the bottom of the page.  I don't want it to be position: fixed (that'd get annoying), but I do want it to appear at the bottom of the page when you scroll all the way down. (In the case that no scrolling is needed, it should appear at the bottom of the window)

Here's what I'm using.  There's probably a pretty simple fix but I don't see what it is.  Copy/paste this and you'll see.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        font-size: 200%;
      }

      #side {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #0A0;
        z-index: 100;
      }

      #header {
        height: 40px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: #A00;
        z-index: 200;
      }

      #header_push {
        clear: both;
        height: 40px;
      }

      #footer {
        height: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: #00A;
        z-index: 150;
      }

      #footer_push {
        clear: both;
        height: 50px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      HEADER
    </div>
    <div id="header_push"></div>
    <div id="content">
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="side">
      SIDE COLUMN
    </div>
    <div id="footer_push"></div>
    <div id="footer">
      FOOTER
    </div>
  </body>
```

Working correctly:

[image: working correctly]

Working incorrectly when scrolling down (see scrollbar on side of page):

[image: working incorrectly with scroll]

Comment: share ur jsfiddle link?

Comment: [Example](http://jsbin.com/educat/1/edit), see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12255692/1763929).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/onopuy/2/edit)

Please modify your **CSS** as below

```
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #00A;
  z-index: 150;
}
```

Remove `bottom: 0;` from `#footer{..}`

Comment: If you remove the contents it won't stick to bottom

Comment: I also facing the same problem but this solution isn't helping my problem :(

Comment: This is not solving the problem - Possible Solution with Vucko answer

Answer (score 6):

You need change the `position` to `fixed`

Comment: Yes, finally. Thanks, this did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

See my comment for an [example](http://jsbin.com/educat/1/edit) of how to do this.

But in you situation, just put `position:relative` on the body.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/obufef/1/edit)

Them the `absolute` position *footer* will be in the `relative` positioned *parent* and will use its space, so putting `bottom:0` will put the *footer* on the bottom of its _parent.

Some [examples of elements with different positions](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Comment: This is a possible solution. It makes sense because this collides with the  behavior of an element with css rule `position:absolute` inside an element with css rule `position:relative`

Answer (score 0):

Hey i made a fiddle using your code. from what i understand this is what you're looking for. let me know if this helps.

Changes done:
**CSS**

```
#footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #00A;
    z-index: 150;
  }
```

Link to fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/daltonpereira/q7Dqg/